# Copying Subscribed Calendar from iPhone to Mac

Tags: calendar, caldav

I have a subscribed calendar on my iPhone. If I look in the *Settings* under *Mail, Contacts, Calendars*, under *Subscribed Calendars*, I see the subscribed calendar.

If I go into the subscribed calendar on my iPhone I see:

```
Account (On)
Server: mobile.server.com/ical.php?uniq_uuid
User Name:
Password: 
Use SSL (On)
Remove Alarms (Off)
```

On my Mac, I go to the Calendar application, and select *Calendar->Add Account*, and then select "Add CalDAV Account...". There are three modes, *Automatic*, *Manual*, and *Advanced*. In the *Manual* mode, I see:

```
Account Type: Manual
User Name:
Password:
Server:
```

If I go into "Advanced", I see:

```
Account Type: Advanced
User Name:
Password:
Server Address:
Server Path:
Port:         Use SSL (checkbox)
Use Kerberos v5 for authentication (checkbox)
```

I have the information I need to enter from my iPhone, but I can't save it on my Mac unless there's a *User Name*, but there isn't one in the iPhone account information.

How can I enter this information from my iPhone to my Mac? My Mac is running Mavericks and the iPhone is running iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a calendar subscription with a calendar account.

What you think of as a "calendar subscription" is merely a publicly readable file in the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) format published using the "ical://" URI. This is a read only list of calendar dates.

[CalDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caldav) or Calendar extension to WebDAV is a protocol to allow a calendar server and a client application to exchange calendar information (by coincidence in iCalendar format). It is the calendar equivalent of an email account.

So you are attempting to add your subscriptions in the wrong spot. As has already been said, in the Calendar application go to the File menu and select "New Calendar Subscription" then paste in the URL.

If you **do** have a CalDAV account you want to add to your Mac then go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts and on the right select "Add Other Account... and one of the choices is "Add a CalDAV Account" and once created here it is available for Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a subscribed calendar (i.e. a URL to an .ics file) you should try the following:

In Calendar.app on your Mac, choose File > New Calendar Subscription and enter the URL from your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering just a space for your username.

Comment: Tried that, but that doesn't work.